# Why do I have to use aes_string() with ggplot in shiny?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I´m new working with shiny and I´m trying to make a ggplot. According to what I have read, I have to use `aes_string` instead of `aes()`, but I am still trying to figure out why.

My code:

```
output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = movies, aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y,
                                     color = input$z)) +
      geom_point(alpha = input$alpha)
  })
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let us take `mtcars` data as an example.

Normally you call `ggplot2` as :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp,color = am)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Notice that you pass `mpg`, `disp` and `am` as bare column names and not as string. When you take user input in shiny you get those as string. So if you don't use `aes_string` what you are calling is :

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = "mpg", y = "disp",color = "am")) + geom_point()
```

[image]

which is not what you want. Hence, by using `aes_string` you "tell" R/Shiny that I am passing column names as string but treat them as columns from the dataframe and not as string.

Also note that `aes_string` has been soft-deprecated and it is recommended to use tidy evaluation using `.data` as @Phil mentioned.

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, 
       aes(x = .data[["mpg"]], y = .data[["disp"]],color = .data[["am"]])) + 
  geom_point()
```

Other options include :

- `sym` with `!!` :

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, 
     aes(x = !!sym("mpg"), y = !!sym("disp"),color = !!sym("am"))) + 
     geom_point()
```

- `get` :

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, 
       aes(x = get("mpg"), y = get("disp"),color = get("am"))) + 
  geom_point()
```

Comment: `.data[["var"]]` is now preferred over `!! sym("var")`. https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: How about using `get(varname)`? It works fine for me but how kosher is that?

Comment: Yes, we can also use `get`. I have updated the answer to include that.