# Shiny App Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm teaching myself r and i'm trying to create a shiny app on NBA data and i'm asking for the name of player and the statistic for the inputs.

```
 textInput("name", "Name", value = "Giannis Antetokounmpo"),
      
 selectInput("stat", "Stat", choices = list("Points Per Game" = "PTS",
                                                 "Rebounds Per Game" = "TRB",
                                                 "Assits Per Game" = "AST",
                                                 "Steals Per Game" = "STL",
                                                 "Blocks Per Game" = "BLK"),
                                                  selected = "PTS"),
```

When trying to create a scatterplot i am getting the error that "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data"

```
    NBA_abv %>% 
      filter(Player == input$name) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = input$stat)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[Here is the dataset i'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQvv6.png)

Comment: Related: [Why do I have to use aes_string() with ggplot in shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63734097/why-do-i-have-to-use-aes-string-with-ggplot-in-shiny)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I have to use aes\_string() with ggplot in shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63734097/why-do-i-have-to-use-aes-string-with-ggplot-in-shiny)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have come across this error once before. If I remember correctly, you need to use `aes_string`

```
    NBA_abv %>% 
      filter(Player == input$name) %>%
      ggplot(aes_string(x = Year, y = input$stat)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```